# Custom implementation of add_r_value_reference and add_l_value_reference

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, c++-templates

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_reference has possible implementations for std::add_lvalue_reference and std::add_rvalue_reference which are followings:

```
namespace detail {
 
template <class T>
struct type_identity { using type = T; }; // or use std::type_identity (since C++20)
 
template <class T> // Note that `cv void&` is a substitution failure
auto try_add_lvalue_reference(int) -> type_identity<T&>;
template <class T> // Handle T = cv void case
auto try_add_lvalue_reference(...) -> type_identity<T>;
 
template <class T>
auto try_add_rvalue_reference(int) -> type_identity<T&&>;
template <class T>
auto try_add_rvalue_reference(...) -> type_identity<T>;
 
} // namespace detail
 
template <class T>
struct add_lvalue_reference
    : decltype(detail::try_add_lvalue_reference<T>(0)) {};
 
template <class T>
struct add_rvalue_reference
    : decltype(detail::try_add_rvalue_reference<T>(0)) {};
```

Do you find any failed scenario for following custom implementation or would it be a more direct and simple implementation that works?

I have added my own test cases to the main for demonstration purpose.

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct add_lvalue_ref {
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
struct add_lvalue_ref<T, std::void_t<T&>> {
    using type = T&;
};

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct add_rvalue_ref {
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
struct add_rvalue_ref<T, std::void_t<T&&>> {
    using type = T&&;
};

int main()
{
    // add_lvalue_ref
    if (std::is_same_v<add_lvalue_ref<int>::type, int&>) {
        std::cout << "add_lvalue_ref same\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "add_lvalue_ref different\n";
    }
    if (std::is_same_v<add_lvalue_ref<const int>::type, const int&>) {
        std::cout << "add_lvalue_ref same\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "add_lvalue_ref different\n";
    }
    if (std::is_same_v<add_lvalue_ref<int&>::type, int&>) {
        std::cout << "add_lvalue_ref same\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "add_lvalue_ref different\n";
    }
    if (std::is_same_v<add_lvalue_ref<const int&>::type, const int&>) {
        std::cout << "add_lvalue_ref same\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "add_lvalue_ref different\n";
    }
    if (std::is_same_v<add_lvalue_ref<int&&>::type, int&>) {
        std::cout << "add_lvalue_ref same\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "add_lvalue_ref different\n";
    }
    if (std::is_same_v<add_lvalue_ref<const int&&>::type, const int&>) {
        std::cout << "add_lvalue_ref same\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "add_lvalue_ref different\n";
    }
    if (std::is_same_v<add_lvalue_ref<void>::type, void>) {
        std::cout << "add_lvalue_ref same\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "add_lvalue_ref different\n";
    }
    if (std::is_same_v<add_lvalue_ref<const void>::type, const void>) {
        std::cout << "add_lvalue_ref same\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "add_lvalue_ref different\n";
    }
    if (std::is_same_v<add_lvalue_ref<int(int)>::type, int(&)(int)>) {
        std::cout << "add_lvalue_ref same\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "add_lvalue_ref different\n";
    }
    if (std::is_same_v<add_lvalue_ref<int(int) const>::type, int(int) const>) {
        std::cout << "add_lvalue_ref same\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "add_lvalue_ref different\n";
    }


    // add_rvalue_ref
    if (std::is_same_v<add_rvalue_ref<int>::type, int&&>) {
        std::cout << "add_rvalue_ref same\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "add_rvalue_ref different\n";
    }
    if (std::is_same_v<add_rvalue_ref<const int>::type, const int&&>) {
        std::cout << "add_rvalue_ref same\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "add_rvalue_ref different\n";
    }
    if (std::is_same_v<add_rvalue_ref<int&>::type, int&>) {
        std::cout << "add_rvalue_ref same\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "add_rvalue_ref different\n";
    }
    if (std::is_same_v<add_rvalue_ref<const int&>::type, const int&>) {
        std::cout << "add_rvalue_ref same\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "add_rvalue_ref different\n";
    }
    if (std::is_same_v<add_rvalue_ref<int&&>::type, int&&>) {
        std::cout << "add_rvalue_ref same\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "add_rvalue_ref different\n";
    }
    if (std::is_same_v<add_rvalue_ref<const int&&>::type, const int&&>) {
        std::cout << "add_rvalue_ref same\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "add_rvalue_ref different\n";
    }
    if (std::is_same_v<add_rvalue_ref<void>::type, void>) {
        std::cout << "add_rvalue_ref same\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "add_rvalue_ref different\n";
    }
    if (std::is_same_v<add_rvalue_ref<const void>::type, const void>) {
        std::cout << "add_rvalue_ref same\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "add_rvalue_ref different\n";
    }
    if (std::is_same_v<add_rvalue_ref<int(int)>::type, int(&&)(int)>) {
        std::cout << "add_rvalue_ref same\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "add_rvalue_ref different\n";
    }
    if (std::is_same_v<add_rvalue_ref<int(int) const>::type, int(int) const>) {
        std::cout << "add_rvalue_ref same\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "add_rvalue_ref different\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::void_t` is a C++17 feature, so your `c++11` tag is wrong. Could you explain why you would want to use a custom implementation and not the one provided by the standard library?

Comment: The test cases lack versions like `add_rvalue_ref<int&>` and `add_lvalue_ref<int&&>`, where things can get interesting. Things like `int` -> `int&` always work, and hardly need any helpers.

Comment: @BoP Thanks for the comment and I have updated my question to include those cases.

Comment: Thanks @joergbrech I have removed `c++11` tag and added `c++17`.
I am just trying to see if I can provide a simpler and cleaner (thus hopefully better) implementation that works.

Comment: @HarryNg The [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be a good place for your question